# PHP preg_match: a pattern which satisfies all MySQL field names (including 'table.field' formations)

Tags: php, mysql, regex, preg-match

i need a pattern which satisfies mysql field names, but also with the option of having a table name before it

examples:

```
mytable.myfield
myfield
my4732894__7289FiEld
```

here's what i tried:

```
$pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*?[\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]]?$/";
```

this worked for what i needed before, which was just the field name:

```
$pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/";
```

any ideas why my addition isnt working?

maybe i'm making up regex, so i'll explain what i added...
the first '?' is to say that it isn't greedy, ie. it will stop if the next part, namely "[.[a-zA-Z0-9_]]?" is satisfied. now, that second part is just the same as the first except it is optional (hence the '?' at the end) and it starts with a period (hence the '[.' and ']' wrapping my old clause.
and obviously, the "^" and "$" rep the beginning and end of the string

so... any ideas?

(also, i'm a tad confused as to why i need to put in those "/"s in the begining/end anyways, so if you could tell me why it's required, that'd be awesome)

thanks a lot! (and thanks for reading this all if you actually did... it's quite a ramble)

Comment: Note that `?` matches either one char at most. You probably want to use `+`.

Comment: Are you going to support `\`CRAZY-NAM3$\`.\`like@this?\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[...]` is used to construct a character class. Use `(?:...)` for grouping.

BTW, `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so

```
$pattern = "/^\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)?$/"
```

Note that I have also replaced `*?` with `+`. Since `\w` will never match a `.`, so it's non-greedy matching is not needed (`*?` → `*`). But I don't think `.field` should be valid, so a `+` should be used instead of `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Field names (and table names) can contain almost any character.  The only characters field names don't support are NULL (`0x00`) and trailing spaces.  Table names (and db names) are a little more limiting in that they can also not have a `/`, `\` or `.`...  The only requirement is that you wrap the identifiers with "`" backtick quotes.  If the identifier contains a backtick, escape it with another backtick...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html